# Как перестроить график на html-странице на основе результата выбора данных в форме wtform в веб-приложении на flask?

Tags: canvas, flask, wtforms

Я разрабатываю веб-приложение во flask. В приложении есть база данных. Когда пользователь посещает страницу, он должен увидеть график с данными по умолчанию для первого устройства. Затем есть фильтры, в которых пользователь выбирает желаемое устройство, тип данных и период времени. После нажатия на кнопку "Применить" график должен быть перестроен в соответствии с выбором пользователя. Фильтры выполняются в wtform. График создает скрипт canvas в html. Проблема: График не перестраивается, он все время остается исходным по умолчанию

Код Flask:

```html
@app.route('/chart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chart_view():
    """Chart Page"""
    form = LogChartForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        source_id = form.source_id.data
        type_id = form.type_id.data
        time_start = form.time_start.data
        time_end = form.time_end.data
        source_get = EvSource.query.filter_by(description=source_id).first()
        source = source_get.id_ev_source
        if type_id != 'All':
            typ_get = EvType.query.filter_by(description=type_id).first()
            typ = typ_get.id_ev_type
            items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=source, id_ev_type=typ).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
        else:
            items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=source).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
        # start = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(time_start.year, time_start.month, time_start.day, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
        # end = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(time_end.year, time_end.month, time_end.day, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
        labels = [strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime(item.timestamp)) for item in items]
        datas = [item.value for item in items]
        text = form.source_id.data
        dict_data = {'labels': labels, 'datas': datas, 'texts': text}
        return render_template('chart.html', form=form, **dict_data)
    else:
        source_id = form.source_id.data
        type_id = form.type_id.data
        source_get = EvSource.query.filter_by(description=source_id).first()
        source = source_get.id_ev_source
        items = Log.query.filter_by(id_ev_source=source).order_by(Log.timestamp).all()
        labels = [strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime(item.timestamp)) for item in items]
        datas = [item.value for item in items]
        text = form.source_id.data
        dict_data = {'labels': labels, 'datas': datas, 'texts': text}
        return render_template('chart.html', form=form, **dict_data)
```

Html-код:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div style="width: 100%; display: grid; color: #272d3d;">
    <div style="background-color: #eaeaea; min-height: 50px; width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;">
        <p style="margin: 10px 0 0 30px; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.2;">Current system status: Graph</p>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 30px 5% 30px 5%; height: 50vh;">
        <div>
            <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 100%;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
            const labels = {{ labels | tojson }};
            const texts = {{ texts | tojson }};
            const data = {
              labels: labels,
              datasets: [{
                label: texts,
                backgroundColor: '#E22545',
                borderColor: '#E22545',
                data: {{ datas | tojson }},
              }]
            };
            const config = {
              type: 'line',
              data: data,
              options: { maintainAspectRatio: false }
            };
            const myChart = new Chart(
              document.getElementById('myChart'),
              config
            );
        </script>
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div style="width: 100%; display: grid; color: #272d3d;">
            <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; background-color: #eaeaea; min-height: 50px; border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;">
                <p style="margin: 10px 0 0 30px; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.2;">Filters</p>
                <div style="margin: 10px 30px 0 0; text-align: right;">
                    {{ form.submit(style="height: 30px; width: 140px; font-size: 16px; color: #fbfbfb; background-color: #272d3d; border: none; font-weight: 700;") }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="margin: 30px 5% 30px 5%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr; grid-column-gap: 80px">
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.2; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        Signal source
                    </p>
                    {{ form.source_id(style="height: 25px; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bolder;") }}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.2; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        Signal type
                    </p>
                    {{ form.type_id(style="height: 25px; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bolder;") }}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.2; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                        Period
                    </p>
                    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-column-gap: 20px">
                    {{ form.time_start(class= "datepicker", style="text-align: right; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bolder;") }}
                    {{ form.time_end(class= "datepicker", style="text-align: right; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bolder;") }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: получать данные для графика из БД, отправлять SQL запрос UPDATE и изменять данные.